# Why Try-With-Resources does not create a new instance every time

Tags: java, testng, try-with-resources

I'm trying to write a Unit test using TestNG to save test data to a db. I'm using DataProvider for creating test data as below:

```
    @DataProvider
private Object[][] movieTitles() {
    return  new Object[][] { 
            new String[] { "Golden Eye" },
            new String[] { "Troy" }, new String[] { "Gladiator" },
            new String[] { "Ring" }, new String[] { "The Village" } };
}
```

And my test case is using try-with-resources as below:

```
    @Test(dataProvider = "movieTitles")
public void save(String title) {
         EntityTransaction tx = null;
     try(PersistenceUtil util = PersistenceUtil.getUtil()){ 
         Movie movie = new Movie(title);
     EntityManager em = util.getManager();
         tx = util.getTransaction();    
        tx.begin();
        em.persist(movie);
        tx.commit();
        Assert.assertTrue(movie.getId() > 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if(tx.isActive())
            tx.rollback();
        e.fillInStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}
```

The first data is saved successfully. However, the PersistenceUtil in the try block is not created/initialized again and thus EntityTransaction is null. And thus a NPE exception occurs for the rest of the data. Why is PersistenceUtil not initialized again in the try-with-resources block. Is there anyway to achieve the same?

Comment: What kind of persistence package is that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug has nothing to do with automatic resource management. The `try` block will execute `getUtil()` each time the `save()` method is called.

The problem lies in the `PersistenceUtil` class; `getUtil()` is returning a non-null `PersistenceUtil`, but it's not behaving properly, and returns `null` from `getTransaction()`.

Comment: Yep, right I found the issue with my `PersistenceUtil` which is a singleton class. It was returning the same instance of PersistenceUtil but the resources were already closed in the         `close()` method. After nullifying the `PersistenceUtil`'s singleton instance in the `close()` method, the problem goes away.Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you persistence layer stays live after `util.close()` has been called at the end of the try-with-resources.

Note also that you can simplify the Object matrix creation:

```
public class Main {

   static Object[][] array = {  { "a", "b" } , { "c", "d" } } ;

   // test print
   public static void main(String[] argv) {
      for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
         Object[] sub = array[i];
         for (int j=0;j<sub.length;j++) {
            System.out.println(sub[j]);
         }
      }
   }

}
```